# how to subtract two time string (HH:MM) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, time

I have two time strings like 03:01 and 01:19 . I want to subtract these two,
I tried like below,

```js
var time1= "03:01".split(':');
var time2= "01:19".split(':');
var minutes = Math.abs(Number(time1[1])-Number(time2[1]));
var hours = Math.floor(parseInt(minutes / 60));
hours = Math.abs(Number(time1[0])-Number(time2[0])-hours);
minutes = minutes % 60;
if(hours.toString().length == 1){
  hours = '0'+hours;
}
if(minutes.toString().length == 1){
  minutes = '0'+minutes;
}
console.log(hours+':'+minutes);
```

> Expected Answer -> 01:42
>
> Actual Answer -> 02:18

Can someone tell me,where I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you check the data type of your variables time1 and time2?

Comment: `var hours1 = Number(time1.split(":")[0])` might help you

Comment: @Rafalon  It's in the correct format only `var time1= document.getElementById('id1').value.split(':');
                  var time2= document.getElementById('id2').value.split(':');`

Comment: Well, this is not what you wrote in your question. You might want to edit your question to include this, as it is relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a couple of utility functions like below might help.

Basically `strToMins` convert string to minutes.
and `minsToStr` to convert back to a string.

Example below.

```js
var time1= "03:01";
var time2= "01:19";

function strToMins(t) {
  var s = t.split(":");
  return Number(s[0]) * 60 + Number(s[1]);
}

function minsToStr(t) {
  return Math.trunc(t / 60)+':'+('00' + t % 60).slice(-2);
}

var result = minsToStr( strToMins(time1) - strToMins(time2) );
console.log(result);
```

Comment: And also we might want to ask why OP expected answer is `01:41` where it obviously should be `01:42`

Comment: @Rafalon Sorry, My mistake that is 01:42 only